# android get scroll position of listview populated with varied height

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In android, how do i get the scroll position of the listview?

I know that I can retrieve the scroll position of a uniform populated listview with the following code:

```
int scrollY = -this.getChildAt(0).getTop() + this.getFirstVisiblePosition()* this.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
```

the code assumes all heights of children(item) in the listview to be equal(`this.getChildAt(0).getHeight()`)

Now, if i populate my listview with not equally sized items, how do i get the proper scroll position?

My listview looks something like this:
[image]

This is why I need the scroll position:

```
private Canvas drawIndicator(Canvas canvas) {

    int scrollY = getCurrentScrollPosition();



    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    paint.setAlpha(100);
    canvas.drawRect(getLeft(), indicatorPosition[0] - scrollY, getRight(), indicatorPosition[1]
            - scrollY, paint);

     //Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "drawIndicator:" + (indicatorPosition[1] -
     //scrollY));

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#47B3EA"));
    canvas.drawRect(getLeft(), indicatorPosition[1] - scrollY - (indicatorHeight / 2),
            getRight(), indicatorPosition[1] - scrollY + indicatorHeight, paint);

    return canvas;
}
```

i need to draw a indicator that follows the scroll of the listview

i would invoke it like

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas = drawIndicator(canvas);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: can you explain why you needs the scroll position?

Comment: please check the question, i've added the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you know the size of All your items type:

```
int currentY = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++) {

            int type = listView.getAdapter().getItemViewType(i);
            currentY += getHightForViewType(type);
        }

        int scrollY = -listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() + currentY;
```

and using your adapter:

```
 private int getHightForViewType(int itemViewType) {

        int hightItem;
        switch (itemViewType) {
            case 0:
                hightItem = 100;
                break;

            default:
                hightItem = 60;
                break;
        }
        return hightItem;

    }
```

Comment: This answer is good, however if you wonder why the scroll position is not accurate enough, you also need to consider the divider height by adding it to currentY.

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
private Dictionary<Integer, Integer> listViewItemHeights = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

private int getScroll() {
    View c = listView.getChildAt(0); //this is the first visible row
    int scrollY = -c.getTop();
    listViewItemHeights.put(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(), c.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); ++i) {
        if (listViewItemHeights.get(i) != null) // (this is a sanity check)
            scrollY += listViewItemHeights.get(i); //add all heights of the views that are gone
    }
    return scrollY;
}
```

This should be invoked in:

```
public void onScroll(AbsHListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
```

will work only when scrolling from position 0 was done manually, not programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same problem, but I used listView with random lenght text inside each item hence I don't know  item height in advance.
My implementation:

```
private static int[] heights;

public static int getScrollY(ListView lv) {
  if (heights == null || lv.getCount() != heights.length) {
        heights = new int[lv.getCount()];
    }
    View c = lv.getChildAt(0);
    if (c == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int firstVisiblePosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    if (firstVisiblePosition < lv.getCount() && heights[firstVisiblePosition + 1] == 0) {
        heights[firstVisiblePosition + 1] += heights[firstVisiblePosition] + c.getHeight();
    }
    return -c.getTop() + heights[firstVisiblePosition];
}
```

I think there are problems if any element of listView changed (add/remove/change height). Also height computes when you scroll listView and there is problem if you scroll listView programmatically.
This is very sad, that listView implementaion prevents easy access to scroll Y position :(